# Cannot change email template in Mailboxer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mailboxer

I generated mailboxer email view templates with `rails g mailboxer:views`. However no matter how I change these templates my mailboxer emails remain the same. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

Comment: Hi can you display some code your trying to change. and maybe some images so we can help more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that the `rails g mailboxer:views` created proper folders, but in the wrong directory. It created them in the app/views folder instead of app/views/mailboxer. If you have the same issues just move the message_mailer folder inside the mailboxer folder.